# How to handle global style transformations with postcss and webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, postcss

I use webpack2 with postcss for processing styles:

```js
// webpack.config.js
rules: [{
    test: /\.sss$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          camelCase: 'only',
          localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:4]',
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      'postcss-loader',
    ],
}]
```

```js
// postcss.config.js
plugins: {
    'postcss-autoreset': {},
}
```

If I have two `.css` files

```css
/* a.css */
.a {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```css
/* b.css */
.b {
    background-color: red;
}
```

they will be transformed to something like this (I omit `css-modules` names mangling here for clarity):

```html
<style>
    /* transformed a.css content */
    .a {
        all: initial;
    }
    .a {
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<style>
    /* transformed a.css content */
    .b {
        all: initial
    }
    .b {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

And then if I have element like `<div class="a b">blah</div>`, rule `padding: 20px;` wouldn't be applied because reset for `.b` win. To solve this issue, all resets should be "hoisted" like this:

```html
<style>
    .a,
    .b {
        all: initial;
    }
</style>

<style>
    .a {
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<style>
    .b {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a more of an "issue" related to the `postcss-autoreset` plugin. I never used it and this is the first time i see it but after a quick reading of the [Docs](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset#rulesmatcher) it seems that you can pass a rule selector (regex supported) that will make it run through this plugin conditionally.
for Example:

```
postcss([ require('postcss-autoreset')({
  rulesMatcher: (rule)=> rule.selector.match(/[.reset]/)
})])
```

And then you can use the `.reset` css class to auto-reset them.

Comment: Actually, I already use `rulesMatcher` option. It only filters wich selectors will be reseted, but my issue in rules order, not in filtering. I just want to reset all my blocks and elements (in sense of BEM) and expect that they will "just work", even if some block and element will be mixed on one dom element